# 3D animated film with flying motorbike racer and aliens in mech-suits

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the 3D animated film (probably unpopular and barely known), don't know the title and watched only a few minutes of it. I think it was a western animation product, but I only say so, 'cause it was in what we called, y'know, 3d animation thing, before all those 3d cinemas and 3d glasses came around (so, btw, it's not "that" 3d, I meant animation style). I saw this thing around 4 years ago (-ish), but I'm not sure when it came out, possibly earlier. It was in English, but I can't say if that's original language or translation. What I do recall is the protagonist, future flying bike racer barely escaped a massive destruction along with his girlfriend.

Sometime later he survived, she might not and when he woke up, he saw a pair of humanoids like people but in cybersuits and with longer legs. One of which looked like the aforementioned girlfriend, and that humanoid took an interest in him. Kind of dramatic. In more detail: The guy had short black hair(I may not recall that properly), a helmet and had an ordinary build, the girl was blond(-ish). The humanoid woman too, her face looked almost exactly like the girl’s. The male humanoid had other goals, so he mildly called out the female one on her unnecessary interest in a minor specimen (might not be his exact words).

Oh yeah, and more to the story, the destruction happens, the guy is among racers on track, the girl is in audience, when everyone else escape somewhere, he decides to take her with him, later they spend some time together(platonic variation), and then somehow she’s gone (or so he thinks). Then he barely wakes up and blinks to sunlight and sees the female humanoid before him, who he mistakes for the girl, imagining her instead. Google gave me nothing on the matter. If anyone knows what the film's title is appreciated.

Comment: Was this japanese anime or western animation? Can you describe the guy or the girl? Can you describe the "humanoids" in any better detail>

Comment: I think it was a western animation product, but I only say so, 'cause it was in what we called, y'know, 3d animation thing, before all those 3d cinemas and 3d glasses came around (so, btw, it's not "that" 3d, I meant animation style). I saw this thing around 4 years ago (-ish), but I'm not sure when it came out, possibly earlier. It was in English, but I can't say if that's original language or translation. The guy had short black hair (I may not recall that proberly), a helmet and had an ordinary build, the girl was blonde (-ish). The humanoid woman too, her face looked almost exactly like...

Comment: …the girl’s. The male humanoid had other goals, so he mildly called out the female one on her unnecessary interest in a minor specimen (might not be his exact words). Oh, yeah, and more to the story, the destruction happens, the guy is among racers on track, the girl is in audience, when everyone else escape somewhere, he decides to take her with him, later they spend some time together (platonic variation), and then somehow she’s gone (or so he thinks). Then he barely wakes up and blinks to sunlight and sees the female humanoid before him, who he mistakes for the girl, imagining her instead.

Comment: You need to add all of that to the original question.

Comment: Thanks. Done. 'though, still a longshot.

Comment: did you see it in theaters? on tv?

Comment: TV. 'though, Ukrainian one. Sometimes there are things to watch that has no pages on English wikipedia, like Italian cartoons or German films I watched before. And, no, I don't remember the channel, nor the date.

Comment: Welcome, from the TVTropes forum. :)

Comment: BTW, I found it! Elysium (2003). 'though in my memory it had better graphics. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Per the OP's comment above, this was the 2003 animated film [Elysium](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0356577/), not to be confused with the 2013 film of the same name.

Per a [review at beyondhollywood.com](http://www.beyondhollywood.com/elysium-2003-movie-review/):

> ... about an alien race called the Elysians who invades Earth after
>   one of their ambassadors is killed during a diplomatic mission. A
>   full-scale invasion of Earth is ordered by the Elysian’s supreme
>   commander, a General name Necros. Using superior war machines,
>   including giant skyscraper-size walking robots called mechas, the
>   Elysians easily conquer Earth, leaving small remnants hiding in
>   underground shelters. Soon, we learn that three of the survivors are
>   destined to lead the human leftovers to freedom — or at least out of
>   those dinky underground shelters.
>
> One by one, the chosen humans are whisked away from certain death by a
>   mysterious woman who lives in another underground base where three
>   giant mechas also reside. The humans are told they were destined to
>   pilot these mechas against the alien invasion ...

The review includes the following image, presumably taken from the film:

[image]